# NSString - stringWithFormat released automatically

Tags: nsstring, retain, autorelease

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *password;

-(id)init {
...
password=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]];
OR
password=[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
}
```

My problem is that during course of execution at some random point the password object gets automatically released. Effect is same when i use either of the assignments. As soon as i put in a retain, the problem no longer exists. I'm sure there is no release of password object anywhere in the flow - as i mentioned it is in a singleton class. I also checked that the class instance is same even when the password object is released.

Any hints please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the iVar, not the property...
So as you don't use the setter method, your object is not retained.

Use the property instead:

```
self.password = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use...

```
password=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]] retain];
```

Also checkout Apple's doc on [memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html). I would also set breakpoints in your code and see then your object gets released.